# Regex to select words not in an <a> tag

Tags: c#, regex

Using Regular Expression, how do you match a specific word that is **not** in an `<a>` tag.

eg. I am looking for the word `software` that are not a link (ie. not surrounded by `<a ... </a>`)

Sample input

```
... <a href='#'>this software</a> ... software ... <a href='#'>software</a>.
```

Is it possible using regex to match only the second `software`?

If not possible, how do you check in C# if the matched element is inside an `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible** : Yes

**Recommended** : No

There are plenty of HTML parsers out there that might help

Here's a good read about the why it's not recommended: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) . I couldn't put it better even if i'd try

Comment: Hahaha that's an awesome one! But I just want to match 'software' that is not surrounded by <a ... </a>. Do you still recommend using a HTML parser? If so, which is best (ie. simplest) for my need?

Comment: I'd probably dump the html into a string, remove all <a.../a> with a simple replace (simple while loop for start/end will is easy, or a regex as last result because of the above reasons), and then search for my heart content for `software`

Comment: Thanks Noctis! Sorry I didn't mention, I actually want to make this "software" a link , so I need to replace them. (That's why I don't want to touch those that are already links)

Comment: If this is a one time fix, just use Notepad++ and do it. It'll be simpler. Otherwise, run a similar search for starts and ends of links (indexof `<a` and `/a>`) save them in a list as a range of numbers, and then run your indexof `software` to make sure they are not in the range.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully clear on the requirement. The following Regex should hopefully provide some base to what you might be looking for...

```
(?<=\</\w*\>).*
```